# Looking for CAN bus overlay (mcp2515) for ubuntu 22.04 for Orange PI CM4

Tags: raspberrypi, can, orangepi

Trying to start CAN bus @ Orange PI CM4, with the ubuntu 22.04 (custom build from Orange PI team). It has Rockchip RK3566 chip.

I've got stuck on finding valid dt-overlay for mcp2515 chip for this specific board. Pls advise me on where to get that overlay or how to create one. I'm sure its possible to create it based on Ubuntu@RPI4 dt-overlay like this one: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.4.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/mcp2515-can1-overlay.dts

Thank you!